# Why doesn't `exit $?` work as expected in Bash?

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to propagate an exit code in my script, but when I `exit $?` it always seems to exit with 0.

As requested:

```
<some command>
if [[ ! -z "$?" ]]
then
    echo "Some error"
    exit $?
fi
```

Comment: What does your script look like?

Comment: FYI, the default status used by `exit` is `$?`, so `exit $?` is completely redundant.

Comment: We can't possibly answer this without seeing the script. Chances are good it's doing logging or something that sets a new value for `$?`.

Comment: `test -z $?` will ALWAYS exit false. Always. No matter what the value is -- because `$?` will never be an empty string, which is the only thing `test -z` checks for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "Some error"
exit $?
```

`$?` is the exit status of the `echo` command, which will almost always be 0.

Think of `$?` as being very fragile; any command will clobber it.

Also, `-z` is the wrong test; it tests whether its argument is an empty string, not whether it has the value `0`.

If you want to use the exit status of a command later than in the *immediately* following command, save it:

```
<some command>
status=$?
if [[ "$status" -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "Some error" 1>&2
    exit $status
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Just write this:

```
your_command || exit
```

...or, if you want to log:

```
your_command || { retval=$?; echo "Failed" >&2; exit "$retval"; }
```

Since `exit` uses `$?` as its default exit status, the former is the simplest and shortest way of doing this.